# How to implement sliding page like Google Play Movies intro on Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, swipe

I need to implement something exactly like this. Something with a static background, and multiple pages to swipe through. What classes do I need to look at? Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some things I used to implement this:

- a `ViewPager`.
- A vertical `LinearLayout` with two `Space`s (weight of 1 each) and a `RelativeLayout` with a weight of 2
- extended the `RelativeLayout` and overrode its `onMeasure()` to set the width equal to the height.
- red oval shape `drawable` set as the `RelativeLayout`'s background